# How to fill a progress bar via a variable?

Tags: java, android, xml, variables

So I got this green progress bar

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/kcal"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/makros"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light" />
```

My goal is to have this bar transparent at the beginning with a green border. Then I want to have a variable that whenever it get's higher, the progress bar should be filled in relation to the amount of the variable with a green color.
How are these three things possible? Happy to hear any tips concerning this topic!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here there are all documentation with code of example: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html

Use `mProgress.setProgress(mProgressStatus);` to set the % of the progress bar where:

- mProgress is the reference to your progress bar.
- mProgressStatus is a int variable.